Infinite yield possible on Players:WaitForChild("CombatStatus")
I keep getting the error:

"ServerScriptService.CoreScript(Server).CombatScript:13: attempt to index nil with 'CombatStatus'"

In a script I'm working on in a Roblox Game
This line of code is what the error is referring to:
if Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and
    Hit.Parent.Name ~= Player.Name and
    game.Players:FindFirstChild(Hit.Parent.Name).CombatStatus.Value == "" and
    Hitbox.CanTouch == true then

I've tried rewriting the entire scripts, multiple times, but this error keeps happening. I resolved the error, but now have to deal with another one that states:

"Infinite yield possible on 'Players:WaitForChild("CombatStatus")'"


The error means you attempted to get an object that doesn't exist or
an attribute that doesn't exist.

I can't be absolutely certain without more details, but there's a decent chance using WaitForChild could resolve this issue.

You're indexing a nil value with CombatStatus.  That means you need to look for something.CombatStatus something:CombatStatus or something["CombatStatus"] in your code.
You'll find
game.Players:FindFirstChild(Hit.Parent.Name).CombatStatus.Value

So game.Players:FindFirstChild(Hit.Parent.Name) returns nil.
Indexing nil does not make any sense and his hence not allowed and prompted with an error.
Find out why the function returns nil and fix the cause.
If you cannot ensure that a value is indexable, you should not index it without checking.

Thank you SO MUCH for responding, this is the only error I've had the entire time ;-;
